# why is my wordpress installation on gke vm that is connected to cloud sql stuck at step 2?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql

I launched a WordPress website on a GCE VM and connected it to cloud SQL database and the website ran perfectly. However when I did the same but on a GKE cluster the WordPress installation got stuck here: `wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=2`.

It just wouldn't load. I'm not sure whether this is a problem with scopes/permissions or something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you did the same steps to install WordPress in GCE and GKE it will not work cuz its a different service architecture, for GKE you should use and follow the steps for Kubernetes ([WordPress from GCP Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/wordpress?q=wordpress%20kubernetes)); If you already use this steps to deploy your WordPress Containers I would suggest to check Stackdriver Logging to more information about this issue and also retrieve logs from the pods:

- kubectl logs [POD NAME]